# How can I pass a parameter or value from a test case to a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have a fixture `pretest()` like the example below which is intended to be called before every test case. I understand that this fixture is run before running the test case code.

Is there any way to get a value from the test case function so that I can use it inside the fixture?

For example, I need to read `json_name` defined in the test case and print it inside the `pretest` fixture before running the test case.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def pretest(request):
    tc_name = request.node.name
    json_name =    # ==> how can i get this parameter or value from testcase and use here ?
    yield
    
    
def test_case_EVA_01():
    json_name = file1.json


def test_case_EVA_02():
    json_name = file2.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be collecting info about each test case to make a test report.

You can use pytest's [`record_property` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html#record-property) to store arbitrary information from each test case, which then becomes available as part of the test's [`user_properties`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html#record-property):

```
from typing import Callable

import pytest
from pytest import FixtureRequest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def pretest(request: FixtureRequest):
    tc_name = request.node.name

    yield

    # list[tuple[str, object]] => dict[str, object]
    tc_props = dict(request.node.user_properties)
    json_name = tc_props["json_name"]

    # to keep things simple, let's just print it out for now
    print(tc_name, json_name)

def test_case_EVA_01(record_property: Callable[[str, object], None]):
    json_name = "file1.json"
    
    # ... do actual tests ...

    # store test case info
    record_property("json_name", json_name)


def test_case_EVA_02(record_property: Callable[[str, object], None]):
    json_name = "file2.json"

    # ... do actual tests ...

    # store test case info
    record_property("json_name", json_name)
```

First, modify the fixture to make it a [`yield fixture`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended), so that control first starts with the fixture, then passes it to the test function, and then finally back to the fixture. Next, in each test function, call the `record_property` fixture to store the `json_name` value using `"json_name"` as its key. Finally, when control comes back to the fixture (i.e. after `yield`), you can now access the `json_name` value from `user_properties`, which is a list of tuples where each tuple is the same key-value you passed to `record_property`.

Running the tests and turning on `-rP` to output and `print`'s:

```
$ pytest -v -rP test1.py
...
test1.py::test_case_EVA_01 PASSED                                                     
test1.py::test_case_EVA_02 PASSED                                                     
...
--------------------------------- Captured stdout teardown ----------------------------------
test_case_EVA_01 file1.json
--------------------------------- Captured stdout teardown ----------------------------------
test_case_EVA_02 file2.json
```

Now, I don't know your exact use case, but if you *really* are doing this to make a report, I think an `autouse` fixture isn't the most appropriate solution. Instead, it's much better to use one of pytest's [`pytest_runtest_protocol` hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_protocol), specifically the [`pytest_runtest_makereport` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_makereport) when it's called on `report.when=="teardown"`.

There are quite a number of pytest plugins that make use of this hook for generating reports of different formats, but to keep this answer simple, let's just override the hook so that it creates a simple text file listing the test IDs and the JSON names.

If you add this to [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files):

```
import pytest
from pytest import Item, TestReport

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item: Item):
    output = yield
    report: TestReport = output.get_result()

    if report.when == "teardown":
        json_name: str = ""
        if item.user_properties:
            tc_props = dict(item.user_properties)
            json_name = tc_props["json_name"]
        with open("report.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{item.nodeid} ({json_name})")
            f.write("\n")
```

Then run the tests:

```
$ pytest -v test1.py
...
test1.py::test_case_EVA_01 PASSED
test1.py::test_case_EVA_02 PASSED
```

The report should contain:

```
$ cat report.txt 
test1.py::test_case_EVA_01 (file1.json)
test1.py::test_case_EVA_02 (file2.json)
```

Comment: using `record_property` is a good idea, but it did not solve my problem, since i wanted to get the property name before calling `yield`, As i mentioned i need to use some properties inside fixture before running the testcase.

Comment: @SunilKumar Then I think those test case properties (like `json_name`) should be fixtures _themselves_ rather than being defined inside the test functions. Your `pretest` fixture should probably be just a fixture that combines the values from other smaller fixtures (see https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixtures-can-request-other-fixtures). Then each test case would just be using `pretest` which returns/yields test-case-specific values. I am... out of ideas since I'm a bit confused with your setup, sorry. Good luck.

Comment: i solved my problem by using `pytest.mark.parametrize` (submitted in answer section) i am not sure if there is any other easy way.

Answer (score 0):

i could solve my problem using `pytest.mark.parametrize` and passing required data as parameters. i am not sure if there is any other easy way, but below solution worked.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def pretest(request):
    tc_name = request.node.name
    json_name = request.node.callspec.params['json_name'] # json file name can be accessed 
    # testcode to perform pretest (json file is being used)
    yield

@pytest.mark.parametrize("json_name", ["file1.json"])
def test_case_EVA_01(json_name):
    # testcase code with json file is being used

@pytest.mark.parametrize("json_name", ["file2.json"])
def test_case_EVA_02(json_name):
    # testcase code with json file is being used
```